# Finding the Lowest Common Ancestor in a BST using Swift 3 returning nil every time

Tags: swift

I am implementing an algorithm to return the LCA of a BST using Swift 3. However, I am having issues with the Optionals, once I run some test values I am getting nil every time. My test should return 12.

The BST looks like this:

```
             20

        8         22

   4         12

        10        14
```

*Implementation*

```
    class Node {
    var value: Int 
    var leftChild: Node?
    var rightChild: Node?

    init (value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class BinarySearchTree {

    var root: Node?

    /* Function to find LCA of n1 and n2. The function assumes that both
       n1 and n2 are present in BST */
    func findLCA(node: Node?, n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Node? {
        if node == nil {
            return nil
        }

        //traverse left: n1 and n2 are smaller than root
        if (node!.value > n1 && node!.value > n2) {
            print("left: n1: \(n1) n2: \(n2) node \(node!.value)")
            return findLCA(node: node?.leftChild, n1: n1, n2: n2)
        }

        //traverse right: n1 and n2 are greater than root
        if (node!.value < n1 && node!.value < n2) {
            print("right: n1: \(n1) n2: \(n2) node \(node!.value)")
            return findLCA(node: node?.rightChild, n1: n1, n2: n2)
        }

        return node
    }

}

var tree = BinarySearchTree()
tree.root? = Node(value: 20)
tree.root?.leftChild = Node(value: 8)
tree.root?.rightChild = Node(value: 22)
tree.root?.leftChild?.leftChild = Node(value: 4)
tree.root?.leftChild?.rightChild = Node(value: 12)
tree.root?.leftChild?.rightChild?.leftChild = Node(value: 10)
tree.root?.leftChild?.rightChild?.rightChild = Node(value: 14)

var n1 = 10, n2 = 14;
var t = tree.findLCA(node: tree.root, n1: n1, n2: n2) 
print("LCA of \(n1) and \(n2) is \(t?.value)")
```

*Output*

LCA of 14 and 8 is nil

Compile Message:

solution.swift:53:35:

warning: string interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit?

print("LCA of (n1) and (n2) is (t?.value)")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
tree.root? = Node(value: 20)
```

to

```
tree.root = Node(value: 20)
```

And your print should look like:

```
print("LCA of \(n1) and \(n2) is \(t?.value ?? -1)")
```

This will print -1 if your search returns nil.